# Is there any mathematical blog platform that supports LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, mathjax, online

As suggested by the topic, is there any mathematical blog platform that supports LaTeX? I think people commonly use WordPress but I am not sure whether it supports LaTeX as it doesn't show the LaTeX format.

Comment: WordPress supports LaTeX.

Comment: well, but i type $ $ and it didn't really show the format, or do you have any way to use the latex format in wordpress??

Comment: The very first Google hit for "LaTeX Wordpress" is http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/ .

Comment: I got mathJax integrated into my [Blosxom](http://blosxom.com/) blog with very little trouble.

Comment: If you have a blog at wordpress.com then yes, it already supports LaTeX. But if you've installed WordPress from wordpress.org on some server, then you also need to install and activate the LaTeX plug-in.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Wordpress does *not* support LaTeX.  The only way I know of to write in proper LaTeX and have it accepted by a Wordpress blog is to use my `internet` class to preprocess it (as I've done for all my posts on the TeX-SX blog).  Wordpress can support various simulated LaTeX formats for **mathematics** which is probably what is being asked for here.  But then so can every other blog software out there that allows plugins.

Comment: You can also post [onp4.com](https://onp4.com) - it allows you to write math in Markdown using KaTex syntax. [onp4.com/@p4/~math](https://onp4.com/@p4/~math)

Answer (score 20):

For math input one can use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

**Quick instructions**

For me it works to add:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
   jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
   tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [[ '$','$']],
     displayMath:  [['$$','$$']],
     processEscapes: true
   },
   "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"          
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js">
</script>
```

to the header (which can be modified at a lot of blogging websites) of the html document.

After that you can use `$..$` and `$$..$$` to quickly add inline and display style equations, `\begin{..}...\end{..}` works too.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/j8rt5vq6/) is how it looks and works also with different colors.

Answer (score 17):

By 'supporting LaTeX', many people mean 'supporting the use of TeX-like input for mathematical symbols'. That's not the same thing: support LaTeX proper requires a TeX system, supporting just a small subset does not.

Taking WordPress as an example, both TeX-like input and proper LaTeX support are available. By far the most straight-forward way here is to use a plugin to load the appropriate code from elsewhere. MathJax is the technology that is used for example on other StackExchange sites for TeX-like input, and it's available for WordPress using the [JetPack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) plugin. This plugin makes use of the WordPress.com MathJax support. Real LaTeX requires a TeX system installed somewhere, and for most people that is best left to a specialist server. The [QuickLaTeX plugin](http://quicklatex.com/) for WordPress renders LaTeX code as `.png` files 'on the fly', using caching to avoid too much server load and rendering only the parts of a post that need LaTeX support. Thus this solution can deal with cross-references, TikZ and other 'goodies' that MathJax simply cannot.

Answer (score 3):

There is a blog platform called [Functor Network](https://functor.network) that supports latex. It is meticulously crafted for mathematical content. Here is a screenshot
[image]

-- The maintainer of Functor Network

Comment: It looks like you are affiliated with Functor Network? https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: Sure, it's a valid answer, but as the help page I linked to says, that affiliation should be disclosed in any and all relevant answers.

Comment: You've returned to edit this, but have failed to include the required disclosure. While this may not be posted for purely promotional purposes, it promotes a product you're affiliated with without doing anything to advise readers of that fact. Please read the policy @DaiBowen referred you to and edit your answer accordingly.